# maven cannot run junit test for plug-in project

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

I am using "maven-surefire-plugin" to my junit test, but after running "mvn surefire:test", I cannot see any error information and also cannot see the report.

here are my pom.xml

```
<project >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>mygroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myPArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-ALPHA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src</testSourceDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>             
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                  <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>           
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>                
                </includes>
            </configuration>              
          </plugin>         
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please notify that my packaging type is "eclipse-plugin", and here are the output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: com.packtpub.e4:com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\eclipse_workspaceBookNew\com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui\pom.xml
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201710111001/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201710111001/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201709271000/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201709271000/
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: com.packtpub.e4:com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\eclipse_workspaceBookNew\com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui\pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: com.packtpub.e4:com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\eclipse_workspaceBookNew\com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui\pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-cli) @ com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.310 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-27T15:13:45+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/441M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

as you can see, Though there is no error, the tests doesn't run at all.

Comment: Are you sure your tests classes are named properly using `*Test.java` ? (such as `MyFunctionTest.java`)

Comment: Are your tests even compiled? Note that the `eclipse-plugin` packaging doesn’t bind anything to the `test-compile` phase. Also, Tycho uses the information in your `build.properties` rather than POM elements like `<testSourceDirectory>` to determine what will be compiled. So, carefully check what is compiled during a normal `mvn clean install`.

Comment: @PierreB. I am sure the test file name is right.

Comment: @AndreasSewe Thanks, I think you are right, I didn't bind anything do test-compile, here are more information about this:https://mukis.de/pages/simple-junit-tests-with-tycho-and-surefire/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tests are packages in an appropriate directory structure, you might want to use the following configuration instead :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version> <!-- Specific due to memory leak in 2.20 -->
    <dependencies>
         <!--Custom provider and engine for Junit 5 to surefire-->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
             <version>5.0.1</version>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <configuration>
         <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```